# SSRS if statement to return a blank value

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have two columns in my IIF statements called DEPT_CODE and UNIQUE_CODE
what i'm trying to do is return "blank" if the UNIQUE_CODE equals to 2343 else return the DEPT_CODE value.

IIF  UNIQUE_CODE = "2343" Then return " " ELSE return DEPT_CODE value

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically written it..

```
=IIF(Fields!UNIQUE_CODE.Value = "2343", "", Fields!DEPT_CODE.Value)
```

Note that this returns an empty string. In your pseudo code you had a single space. Change as required.

The IIF statement works as follows.

`IIF( <boolean expression to evaluate> , <return this if true>, <return this if false> )`